# Error in solving a nonlinear optimization system with dynamic constraint using openopt and scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve an nonlinear optimal control problem subject to dynamic ( *h(x, x', u) = 0* ) constraint.  
given:  
**f(x) = (u(t) - u(0)(t))^2**    # u0(t) is the initial input provided to the system  
**h(x) = y'(t) - integral(sqrt(u(t))*y(t) + y(t)) = 0**    # a nonlinear differential equation  
**-2 < y(t) < 10**    # system state is bounded to this range  
**-2 < u(t) < 10**    # system state is bounded to this range  
**u0(t)** # will be defined as an arbitrary piecewise-linear function

I've tried to translate the problem into python code using openopt and scipy:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import *
from openopt import NLP
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from operator import and_

N = 15*4
y0 = 10
t0 = 0
tf = 10
lb, ub = np.ones(2)*-2, np.ones(2)*10

t = np.linspace(t0, tf, N)
u0 = np.piecewise(t, [t < 3, and_(3 <= t, t < 6), 6 <= t], [2, lambda t: t - 3, lambda t: -t + 9])

p = np.empty(N, dtype=np.object)
r = np.empty(N, dtype=np.object)
y = np.empty(N, dtype=np.object)
u = np.empty(N, dtype=np.object)
ff = np.empty(N, dtype=np.object)
for i in range(N):
    t = np.linspace(t0, tf, N)
    b, a = t[i], t[i - 1]
    integrand = lambda t, u1, y1 : np.sqrt(u1)*y1 + y1
    integral = lambda u1, y1 : fixed_quad(integrand, a, b, args=(u1, y1))[0]
    f = lambda x1: ((x1[1] - u0[i])**2).sum()
    h = lambda x1: x1[0] - y0 - integral(x1[0], x1[1])
    p[i] = NLP(f, (y0, u0[i]), h=h, lb=lb, ub=ub)
    r[i] = p[i].solve('scipy_slsqp')
    y0 = r[i].xf[0]
    y[i] = r[i].xf[0]
    u[i] = r[i].xf[1]
    ff[i] = r[i].ff

figure1 = plt.figure()
axis1 = figure1.add_subplot(311)
plt.plot(u0)
axis2 = figure1.add_subplot(312)
plt.plot(u)
axis2 = figure1.add_subplot(313)
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

Now the problem is, running the code with a positive initial y0 like **y0 = 10** , the code will result satisfying results.
But giving **y0 = 0** or a negative one **y0 = -1**, nlp problem will be deficient, saying:  
"**NO FEASIBLE SOLUTION has been obtained (1 constraint is equal to NaN, MaxResidual = 0, objFunc = nan)**"  
Also, considering the piecewise-linear initial u0, *if* you put any number other than 0 at the first range of the function at `t < 3`, meaning:  
`u0 = np.piecewise(t, [t < 3, and_(3 <= t, t < 6), 6 <= t], [2, lambda t: t - 3, lambda t: -t + 9])`
  
instead of:  
`u0 = np.piecewise(t, [t < 3, and_(3 <= t, t < 6), 6 <= t], [0, lambda t: t - 3, lambda t: -t + 9])`  
This will result in the same error again.  
Any ideas ?  
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you seem to be solving a 2-dimensional Optimal Control problem as if it were a 1-Dimensional problem.

The constraint dynamics $h(x, x', t)$ are really a second order ODE.

y''(t) - sqrt(u(t))*y(t) + y(t)) = 0

Starting from this I would reword my system as a 2-dimensional, 1st order system in the standard way.

My second thought is that you seem to be optimizing independently, for $u(t)$, at each time step, whereas the problem is to optimize globally for $u(.)$, the entire function. So if anything, the call to NLP should be outside the for loop...

There are dedicated Optimal Control Open Source toolboxes:

Pythonically, there is JModellica: http://www.jmodelica.org/.

Alternatively, I have also successfully used: ACADO, http://sourceforge.net/p/acado/wiki/Home/ (in C++)

Answer (score 0):

There are some very capable modeling tools now such as CasADi, Pyomo, and Gekko that didn't exist when the question was asked. Here is a solution with [Gekko](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). One issue is that `sqrt(u)` needs to have a positive `u` value to avoid imaginary numbers.

[image: Gekko solution]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
u0=1; N=61
m.time = np.linspace(0,10,N)

# lb of -2 leads to imaginary number with sqrt(-)
u = m.MV(u0,lb=1e-2,ub=10); u.STATUS=1
m.options.MV_STEP_HOR = 18 # allow move at 3, 6 time units
m.options.MV_TYPE = 1 # piecewise linear
y = m.Var(10,lb=-2,ub=10)

m.Minimize((u-u0)**2)
m.Minimize(y**2) # otherwise solution is u=u0
m.Equation(y.dt()==m.integral(m.sqrt(u)*y-y))
m.options.IMODE=6
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(7,4))
plt.plot(m.time,u,label='u')
plt.plot(m.time,y,label='y')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.savefig('solution.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```